# How to restrict mouse scroll to modal?

Tags: popup, scroll, modal-dialog, lightbox

I have a modal with scrollable content that works fine using overflow-y: scroll;

Problem is, when using the mouse wheel to scroll inside the modal and you reach the end of the content, the main page then scrolls. My client has asked me to prevent this from happening. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I used the "show" and "hide" events of the modal. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap modal so they have these events, but I guess any good modal plugin will have them. For the "show" event, I binded a function that removes scrolling on the body. For the "hide" event, I binded a function that reenables it. Here's how I did it:

```
modal = $('#myModal');
modal.on('show', function () {
    // disable background scrolling
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
modal.on('hide', function () {
    // enable background scrolling
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

You can of course disable/enable scrolling on the container of your choice. Hope this helps.